# error : type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

I use firestore to retrieve my database as a list of maps but when I try to use it it say

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List'

it says it is an future and I want to transform it to List

Thank you

```
CollectionReference _collectionRef =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('code');

getData() async {
  // Get docs from collection reference
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = _collectionRef.get();

  // Get data from docs and convert map to List
  final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) async => doc.data()).toList();
  print(allData);

  return allData;
}
```

update :

This is the code without the await/sync :

```
'
CollectionReference _collectionRef =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('code');

getData() {
  // Get docs from collection reference
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = _collectionRef.get();

  // Get data from docs and convert map to List
  final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
  print(allData);

  return allData;
}'
```

the same message appears:

```
 `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>`
```

Comment: You can't use an async function inside map - and, in this case, is it even necessary as you are just trying to call `doc.data()`

Comment: I just want to transform the return of this fonction to an variable that i can use

Comment: as @RichardHeap said, it should be enough to just remove the unnecessary `async` keyword `querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();`

Comment: Still not working. It say is an type  future<Dynamic>

Comment: ` getData() {
  // Get docs from collection reference
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = _collectionRef.get();

  // Get data from docs and convert map to List
  final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
  print(allData);

  return allData;
}` if i remove async the code doesnt work at all

Comment: Time to update the question with your new code and error - indicate the line identified in the stack trace.

Comment: Please read the documentation of the tools your using before posting on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
change `getData()` to `Future<List> getData()`